# call controller action method from javascript in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to call controller  method **NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic** from partial view add button.
But using this code, I got 404 error. Please help me as I am new to .net core mvc.

button in partialview

```
<button id="add-characteristics" onclick="add()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Characteristics</button>
```

Test.cshtml

```
function add(){
          var action = ' @Url.Action("NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic", "Blended")';
          window.location.href = action;
          $.post(url)
           .done(function (partialView) {
                  ('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
              });
 }
```

controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic(Characteristic Characteristic)
        {
            return PartialView("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", Characteristic ?? new Characteristic());
        }
```

Comment: Couple issues, `window.location.href` will redirect. Your action is flagged POST, this is causing the 404.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to redirect the user to the action as a new page *and* trying to invoke an AJAX request.  It should be one or the other.

If you want to do this:

```
window.location.href = action;
```

Then you're redirecting the user, which is a GET request.  So remove the `[HttpPost]` from the action method.  (And remove the AJAX call from the JavaScript code, since you don't need it anymore.)

On the other hand, if you want to do this:

```
$.post(url)
    .done(function (partialView) {
        ('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
    });
```

Then just remove this line from your JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = action;
```

It *appears* that the latter (AJAX) operation is what you want, but it's up to you.

---

**Edit:** You also forgot to invoke the jQuery function here:

```
('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
```

should be:

```
$('#Characteristics').append(partialView);
```

Comment: i removed window.location.href = action; but it not return me partial view.

Comment: @Upkar: When you debug, what specifically happens?  Open your browser's debugging tools and observe.  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?

Comment: yes, i got 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Upkar: Then you'll need to debug that error.  Is any useful error information returned in the response body?  If not, can you update the .NET application's config to return error information in development?  When the server-side code is debugging, are any exceptions thrown/caught?

Comment: It throw me this error : Uncaught TypeError: "#Characteristics".append is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: @Upkar: You have a typo.  I've updated the answer to correct that as well.  You forgot to invoke the jQuery function with the `$`.

Comment: thanks @david, you save me.

Comment: hey @david, can you please answer my this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150307/view-data-not-come-into-model-in-net-core-mvc