# view data not come into model in .net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

The data entered into second partial view not come into model but first partial view data come. I want both partial view data into model. Please guide me how to do it as i am new in .net core.

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic(ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Characteristic characteristics)
        {
            return PartialView("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", characteristics ?? new ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Characteristic());
        }
```

First partial view having second partial view

```
@model ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Individual.IndividualSearch

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("IndividualSearches"))
{<div id="Characteristics" class="mb-3">
            @if (Model?.Characteristics != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model?.Characteristics.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @{ Html.RenderPartial("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", Model.Characteristics[i], new ViewDataDictionary()); }
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

IndividualSearch Class

```
 namespace ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Individual
{
public List<Characteristic> Characteristics { get; set; } = new List<Characteristic>();
```

Model

```
namespace ABC.Core.Models.DTOs
{
    public class Characteristic
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

second partial

```
@model ABC.Core.Models.DTOs.Characteristic

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Characteristics"))
{
    <div id="characteristic-details" class="card">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Name", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
```

Service class

```
 individualSearch.Characteristics = requestTestData.individualCharacteristics;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show data by two related partial view, you should confirm which is the first partial to show first.

According to your code, the `IndividualSearchPartial` partial view called `IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial` partial view, therefor, **you should call IndividualSearchPartial partial view first in NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic action which will called IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial partial view automatically.**

And in `NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic` action, you should return `IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial`  partial view with `IndividualSearch` model data.

Here is an example based on your code:

Test view:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Test</h1>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
<div id="aa"></div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/home/NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic",
                type: "post",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#aa").html(data);
                }
            })

        })
    </script>

}
```

NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewIndividualSearchCharacteristic()
        {
             
            IndividualSearch individualSearch = new IndividualSearch()
            {
                Characteristics = new List<Characteristic>() {
             new Characteristic(){  Name="aa", Value="gfd"},
             new Characteristic(){  Name="bb", Value="dsa"},
             new Characteristic(){  Name="cc", Value="eqw"},
            }
            };
            return PartialView("IndividualSearchPartial", individualSearch);
        }
```

IndividualSearchPartial  partial view:

```
@model IndividualSearch

@using (Html.BeginForm("IndividualSearches"))
{
    <div id="Characteristics" class="mb-3">
        @if (Model?.Characteristics != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model?.Characteristics.Count; i++)
            {
        <div class="form-group">
         
            @await Html.PartialAsync("IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial", Model.Characteristics[i])
        </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

IndividualSearchCharacterisiticPartial partial view:

```
@model Characteristic

@using (Html.BeginForm("Characteristics"))
{
    <div id="characteristic-details" class="card">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-*-*">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Name", new { @class = "form-control-label" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the test code:

[image]